# Is there an http-API for Siemens Logo

Tags: .net, automation

I have to renew an old house automation system and am thinking about the Siemens Logo control system. A requirement is that the states of the input and output ports can be read from a c# application.
Since some of the logo modules have Ethernet ports, I thought that they probably support reading and writing the port states via http. However, I have not found information about such a feature.

Is there someone reading and writing the port-states of a Siemens Logo from within c#? Is there a documented API, hopefully a HTTP-API? Or can someone recommend me another automation system, which has such an API?

Comment: Been seeing a lot of interest in Belkin WeMo recently (eg [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com) supports it)

Comment: You can use Z-Wave with Z-Way/RaZberry to control light/heating. Z-Way is a home automation software for Z-Wave and has HTTP/JSON API to communicate with the world. You can also write JavaScript code to make rules and scenes. http://razberry.z-wave.me

Comment: @HCL. Over time S7-1200 PLC were introduced that has this option as Tobias stated in his answer. You might want to reconsider best answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know this question is now over 2 years old, but just for the sake of completeness and if somebody stumbles over this question while looking for an Siemens Logo HTTP-API:

The newer modules (0ba7 and 0ba8) are equipped with an ethernet port and therefore capable of speaking the S7 protocol. There are free libs out in the net implementing this protocol like [libnodave](http://libnodave.sourceforge.net/) or snap7.

I implemented some sort of a "middleware" with C#/WCF which is communicating trough libnodave with the Logo and exposing a simple REST/JSON API for controlling. Thanks to MONO this also runs on the good old Raspberry Pi 24/7 with low power consumption. You can find it [here](http://www.frickelzeugs.de/logocontrol/), unfortunately my site is in german language only.

Comment: Hi Tobias, would you be able to share a source code snippet for how you have used libnodave to connect and read data? Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

I am new to the Siemens Logo automation system.

If it supports HTTP (not HTTPS), and you want to reverse-engineer the API, then you might be able to sniff the messages sent to the Ethernet interface.

However this task is brutal, at least you have enough time/patience, I wouldn't recommend it.

You have more options in the market. Anything that supports X10 (ancient), Insteon or Z-Wave might get you in the right direction.

I have experience with Insteon.They charge $200 for the SDK, and rumors say that the SDK is not well documented and developing can be a pain, but there's a free library that you can get here.

http://soapboxautomation.com/support-2/fluentdwelling-support/

You only need the modem COM / USB and you're ready to control X10 and Insteon devices.

Answer (score 3):

On the newest Logo 8 with the built-in web server, it is possible, and not even that difficult.

I'm documenting my findings here: https://github.com/jankeymeulen/siemens-logo-rest, maybe one day I will write a wrapper, but it's pretty straightforward to use it e.g. with Node-RED.

E.g. to read the status from I1:

`curl 'http://192.168.1.100/AJAX' -H 'Security-Hint: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456' --data-binary 'GETVARS:v1,129,0,0,1,1'`

Security hint you'll need to sniff once, but it can be reused indefinitely (from the same IP address).

Answer (score 1):

Look up "Application examples for LOGO!", download, read the source.

also random googling gets you "I have found a useful tool for studying communication protocols of LOGO under setup directory Program Files\Siemens\LOGOComfort_V5\lib\classes.jar..." doesn't look like HTTP at first glance, not even clear if it is based on tcp and not, say, udp, yet it does appear to be a good start, try to recreate that chap's dev environment and I think you're solid.

also below, assuming you have same generation controller:

[http://wiki.ibhsoftec.com/en/OPCServer:Variables_from_LOGO!_RCE](http://wiki.ibhsoftec.com/en/OPCServer%3aVariables_from_LOGO!_RCE)

and here's a library, supposedly supports C#:

http://www.adontec.com/index.htm?GO=/s7-library.htm

Comment: in other words, looks pretty low-level. think hard if you really want to spend your time on this.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not available and, as far I know the LOGO, will not be available. Ethernet does not mean that the product has a web server, e-mail etc. etc.. Just the possibility to communicate (status) data via the Ethernet layer. Profinet IO for instance.

The LOGO is a simple plc, more a time clock than a PLC, that has a simple processor. You should start looking at a stronger/different product than the LOGO for you requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have a proposition for such a stronger product?

Answer (score 0):

Siemens have no official API for LOGO!. From what I know from other users here, is not going to come up with one.

You can however try this LOGO! API Middleware server.

https://www.ambersys.net/

Your LOGO! needs to be accessible over the internet.

Reading the Data from I1-I4, M1-M4, AI1-AI4, AM1-AM4.
Can Trigger Function Key F1-F4

What the data contains and what the Function keys trigger will depends on your LOGO! program.

You can create a LOGO Key and use this format to retreive data from your LOGO!
https://www.ambersys.net/api?logokey=(the created logokey)